# Объединение нескольких DF в цикле

Tags: python, pandas

Итак, есть исходный DF:

`Com    Res
1   5
1   6
1   6
1   5
1   4
2   5
2   6
2   8
2   7`

Нужно для каждого отдельного значения `Com` создать столбец который показывает дельту `Res`.
То есть на выходе нужно получить вот это:

`Com    Res Delta
1   5   -
1   6   1
1   6   0
1   5   -1
1   4   -1
2   5   -
2   6   1
2   8   2
2   7   -1`

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы добиться такого результата, можно сгруппировать датафрейм по столбцу "Com" с помощью метода [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) и применить к столбцу "Res" метод [`diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), который для каждой группы посчитает разницу между соседними элементами.

```
df['Delta'] = df.groupby('Com')['Res'].diff()
df['Delta'] = df['Delta'].fillna('-')  # Заполним пустые значения '-'
```